# Override onDraw method so it prints respectively to android:alignParentLeft

Tags: android, xml, custom-controls, android-relativelayout

I have a problem positioning my custom view on application screen. 
I would like to override onDraw method so that it 'knows' where to draw, as specified in "android:layout_alignParentLeft.
Currently it draws in marginLeft and marginTop, no matter where my 'tank' is.
Any ideas how I can fix this?

XML file:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tank"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/tank" />

<pl.edu.agh.scada.graphicalObjects.AnalogBar
    android:id="@+id/analogBar"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tank"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tank"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    custom:editable="true"/>
```

And a part of my class retrieving information about custom view:

```
int width;
int height;
public AnalogBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    boolean editable;
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.AnalogBar, 0, 0);
    if (!isInEditMode())
        parentView = ((MainActivity) context).fragment;
    try {
        editable = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.AnalogBar_editable, false);
       //I deleted everything else regarding custom properties
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
    if (editable)
        this.setOnClickListener(new WriteRegisterListener());
    init();
}

public void init() {
    if (!isInEditMode())
        parentView.addViewToList(this);
```

To get information about layout after it is placed on the screen I overrided:

```
public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    width = w;
    height = h;
```

I tried different functions: getX(), getLocationOnScreen()
But it still writes on absolute position saved in marginLeft and marginTop.
Is there a way to get information needed to draw a view in position related to toLeftOf and toStartOf?

**Fortunately I managed to do it.**
I suspected I had to retrieve the position of the layout somehow. As it turns out, when you draw in your view at the '0' position on the left it is at the very left end of the layout.
That way if you parametrise it properly

```
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tank"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tank"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
```

you can draw your custom view where it should be drawn. 
For example, if you want to fill all view with rectangle you have to retrieve its size (like I did in onSizeChanged) then draw rectangle with canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, border);

I do not know why but these parameters (alignBottom&alignLeft) seem to work better than toLeftOf and toEndOf.
**What is the difference between these parameters?**

Answer (score 0):

A view starts after the **margin**, and draws the child views taking **padding** into account (as an inner margin for the childs).
In this case, if you want your view to get drawn aligned to the left of the parent, you shouldn't layout your custom view with:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
```

unless you *really* want a space between the parent and your view.

The other thing is that your setting the position of your custom view relative to that of the tank:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tank"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tank"
```

So you could try:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

Hope it helps.